# Removing objects from an array, objects having value which match a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript array given below, I am trying to remove objects which match level pattern with the parent element. for example, if the type is parent and level is 1-2 then I want to remove child which have level 1-2-1, 1-2-2, 1-2-3

```
var arr = [{
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-1",
  },
  {
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-2",
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-1",
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-2",
  },
  {
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-3",
  } {
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-3",
  }
];
```

I am trying to get it done using regex but not really able to do it right now. can someone please help me out? Or if there is any lodash method which can be used?

**Update**

Here is what I tried so far, I know it's not using regex but probably it can do what I am looking for.

```
var parentLevel = "1-2" + "-";
var length = arr.length;
for (var k = 0; k < length; k++) {
  if (arr[k].Level.startsWith(parentLevel)) {
    arr.splice(k, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you've tried?

Comment: I would have used another structure, like a tree, and then remove by lvl of the tree

Comment: Can you proved any code that you have tried so far?  What is expected to be returned.  Do you want an array of objects that would have all the parents and only children that don't have a parent? Basically what would the array look like once the children that match the pattern are removed.

Comment: `arr.filter(obj => obj.type !== 'child' || !obj.Level.match(/^1-2\b/))`

Comment: @Lewis I have updated the question please have a look

Comment: @Juangarcia the reason I am using flat structure is it minimizes the over use of ng-repeat on frontend and makes the page more responsive.

Comment: @hajile78 Basically I want to remove all the childrens from above array, so the remaining will be only parents in the array.

Comment: Instead of down-voting the questions please help me to ask it in better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve that.

```js
var arr = [{
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-1",
  },{
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-2",
  },{
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-1",
  },{
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-2",
  },{
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-3",
  },{
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-4-3",
  },{
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-3",
  }
];

var nodetoberemoved = "1-2";
var result = arr.filter(function(elem){
        return !elem.Level.indexOf(nodetoberemoved+"-")==0;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I cant really check if the object is parent or child, as it is going to be a multilevel hierarchy.

Comment: U mean if there is a child with `Level 1-4-3` and another child with `Level 1-4-3-5` then the former is a parent of the latter. Then you should remove the second one ?

Comment: Or if you want to remove the `parent` also. Like if I have a `Level 1-2` then I should remove the objects with `Level 1-2-*` no matter if its type is `parent` or `child` ?

Comment: I have bind this data to view in a tree view, so if I click on a tree node I want to remove all the children's of that parent node.

Comment: You want to remove just the childrens or including the node you click ?

Comment: Just the childrens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172672/discussion-between-vignesh-raja-and-nilesh-mahajan).

Answer (score 0):

```
removeChildren("1-2", arr)

removeChildren = (parent, arr) => {
  const regex = new RegExp("^" + parent + "-[0-9]+$")
  return arr.filter(a => !regex.test(a.Level))
}
```

Note: Keep in mind that this only removes the direct children. If you want to remove all sub children use `new RegExp("^" + parent + "[\-0-9]+$")`

Comment: I have modified the question, mean while I will give a try to what you have suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a dynamic solution for what you are wanting.

```
var arr = [{
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-1",
  },{
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-2",
  },{
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-1",
  },{
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-2",
  },{
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-2-3",
  },{
    type: "child",
    Level: "1-4-3",
  },{
    type: "parent",
    Level: "1-3",
  }
];

//Separate the parents and children into two arrays so we can loop through them.
var parents = arr.filter(elem => elem.type === 'parent')    
var children = arr.filter(elem => elem.type === 'child')

//Loop over arrays to remove children from the variable arr
parents.forEach(parent => {
    // Dynamically build a regex to filter out the children
    var regEx = new RegExp("^" + parent.Level + "-");

    children.forEach(child => {
        //if child matches a parent level it will be removed from the original arr variable
        if(regEx.test(child.Level)){
            arr.splice(arr.indexOf(child, 0),1)
        }
    })
})
```